# String splitting - tabs only, not newlines (from Google Sheet)

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to process data pasted in from a Google Sheet (that's the use case that I need to cover). I'm fine, unless there's a block of text with newlines in one of the cells (which is the easiest way for the user to read what they're doing in that particular cell).

I'm looking to deal with each row of the sheet cell by cell.

I'm dealing with it like this:
```

```
rawtext = g.cleaned_data['importtext'].encode('utf8')

rawtext = "".join(rawtext)
rawtext = rawtext.split("\n")
newstandards = []
for lines in rawtext:
    row = re.split(r'\t+', lines)
```

```

Comment: what happens with the approach you have mentioned?

Comment: I think that I'm getting the newlines inside that cell causing there to be extra rows (the initial split by `\n`)

Comment: What is in `rawtext` **before** `rawtext = "".join(rawtext)`? Maybe it is already what you need?

Comment: what happens if you do `for line in rawtext: 
print(line)`  sorry for it being in 1 line cant have newlines

Comment: I can't recall why I did the join, but what's in there before still isn't it, because the split on newlines just chops it up, leaving the row split.

Comment: If I do that, it prints every character individually